# Php get query filters and url parameters

Tags: php, url, filter, parameter-passing

I'm working on new ads website. I try to make an search page where I will display filters like:

```
<h2>Make</h2>
<a href="index.php?page=search&make=renault">Renault</a>
<a href="index.php?page=search&make=mazda">Mazda</a>
<a href="index.php?page=search&make=bmw">BMW</a>
...

<h2>Year</h2>
<a href="index.php?page=search&year=2013">2013</a>
<a href="index.php?page=search&year=2012">2012</a>
...
```

All links are created dynamical with php. When a filter is clicked the current link becomes 
index.php?page=search&key=value&key1=value1 ... . But how to update the other links to new current link if there are 2 filter or to replace other links if the same filter is clicked. I am thinking to store filter string with $_SESSIONS and add a reset button but I am not sure that's a good idea.

Thanks!

Comment: If I get what you're asking, you want to get multiple values from the URL, right? If so, `$search_value = $_GET['search'];` and use the variables in your SQL `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use .htaccess rewrite rules, the following parameter holds your current requested URI:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

So you can build your link by appending that.